# Can immutable data on Daedalus be backed up and restored for quicker wallet installation/update?

Tags: daedalus, wallet

How about just backup and restore `chain/immutable` directory for Daedalus installation or updates, even across machines. Can that avoid the wallet downloading it again after the installation?
Also, are there other directories with just immutable data that can be handled so?

*PS: The dir is as seen in Windows machine.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The biggest time requirement with a fresh install of Daedalus is syncing the node from scratch since Daedalus run a full cardano-node under the hood. You can install Daedalus, let it start, quit, copy over the node database, and then let it run again. Now, if the database was made with an older version, the node may have to re-run through the whole thing but then you are CPU bound and not network bound (download speed) so it will probably still be faster depending on hardware and network specs.

Answer (score 1):

If you just update Daedalus, you don't need to re-download the full blockchain.
I haven't tested copy pasting the data from one Daedalus installation to another, but I'd expect that this should work.

In case you wonder why it takes long to initialize the blockchain after the latest `4.1.0` update:

> After upgrading, you will need to wait at least 30 minutes for Daedalus to start. This is due to changes in the block storage mechanism which requires a full verification of the locally-stored copy of the Cardano blockchain.

For most updates, this should not be the necessary and you can just use the already downloaded blockchain data.

Source: https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/900006759746-Daedalus-4-1-0-release-notes